# SQL to select the second smallest value by user

Tags: mysql

I would like to get a list with the dates of the second purchase only

I have the following list:

```
    Order_id     User_id       Purchase_date
    1            1             01/01/2018
    2            1             02/01/2018
    3            1             02/01/2018
    4            2             03/01/2018
    5            2             03/01/2018
    6            3             01/01/2018
    7            3             02/01/2018
```

Desired result:

```
    user_id       2nd_purchase_date
    1             02/01/20181 
    2             03/01/2018
    3             02/01/2018
```

Thank you

Comment: why user_id=1 has 2nd purchase_date= 01/01/2018?  it should be 02/01/2018, isn't?

Comment: sorry that was a typo. already corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9cf14d/3)

You can do it like below :

```
select user_id, Purchase_date AS '2nd_purchase_date'
from yourtable
where order_id in (
    select min(order_id)
    from yourtable T1
    where order_id > (
        select min(order_id)
        from yourtable
        where user_id = T1.user_id
    )
    group by user_id
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked but in live database the query took too long and it time-out.
In not live database it worked well, just a bit long.
thank you again

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id, Purchase_date AS '2nd_purchase_date' 
FROM my_table 
LIMIT 1,1 
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY Purchase_date
```

Comment: Thank you, what about for the cases that the max() is not the second purchase date? Lets say for example user 1 third purchase would be on 03/01/2018.

Comment: the `Limit x,y` will help it means `start at this row 'x', get this number of rows 'y'` so if you want number three `LIMIT 2,1` but remember in mysql it's zero indexed so getting only record ONE is `LIMIT 0,1`, also I edited the max() it wouldn't have worked

Answer (score 0):

This is alternative answer when order_id is sorted properly according to purchase_date.

```
SELECT user_id,
       purchase_date as '2nd_purchase_date'
from (   
SELECT a.order_id,
      a.user_id,
      a.Purchase_date,
      count(b.user_id) + 1 as rank
FROM  tbl a left join tbl b on a.order_id>b.order_id and a.user_id=b.user_id 
GROUP by  a.order_id,
      a.user_id ) t
where t.rank = 2      
order by user_id
```